# Ultrawide Micro Four Thirds lens: is it better to use a wide full frame lens with a Speed Booster or a native lens?

Tags: lens-adapter, micro-four-thirds, ultra-wide

I am trying to find a cheap solution for an ultrawide fast lens on micro four-thirds. I already own a manual speed booster with a reducing lens and aperture blades. I'm looking to create a full frame equivalent of 15-30mm and a max. aperture bigger than f2.8.

Considering all things manual, is it better to use a wide full frame lens with a speed booster on a µ4/3 camera, rather than a native lens? µ4/3 lenses are rather expensive for me (I'm talking above US$500), considering the additional stop of max. aperture that I gain with the adapter?

I know that the question is rather generic, but I'm having fun filming on the cheap o_0

Comment: Please define "better". Are you primarily concerned with the absolute best image quality possible? The lowest cost? The "sweet spot" between IQ and cost? Something else?

Comment: I'm extremely happy with the Olympus 7-14 in terms of quality, but it wasn't cheap. Far sharper than my Rokinon full-frame primes, which don't really get good in my experience until 35mm and longer. Then again, it's conceivable I just had bad luck of it draw with Rokinon.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to get the native lens. Because you will *never* find a low-cost 15-30mm equivalent rectilinear lens for MFT in full-frame glass.

You do get, that even with a speedbooster at x0.71, that with MFT crop factor, you are looking for 7.5-15mm/0.71 => 10-20mm lens, right?  The smaller your sensor format is, the more difficult it will be to adapt full frame glass to go wide on it.  25mm is *normal* on MFT. Wide starts at 12. And ultrawide? 7mm.

And those focal lengths only really exist for APS-C digital-era glass, not vintage full-frame (where even 24mm may be hard to find, and 18mm is a prized rarity). And sure in modern digital full-frame glass, Canon makes an EF 11-24 f/4L lens, but it's $3k.

And in my book, the additional stop you get from the speedbooster? Doesn't matter if you aren't actually going ultrawide if that's what you're after.

A native lens like the 7-14 or the Oly 9-18 won't be nearly as big/heavy/expensive as a full-frame lens+adapter.  An ultrawide is a more extreme, exotic lens. As such, there really are no super-cheap paths to getting one. Well, maybe the Samyang/Rokinon 12mm f/2 and 10/2.8 lenses. :)

Comment: This is exactly where I was stuck, Thanks for the clarification.
In fact I was considering the  Samyang/Rokinon 12mm f/2 and 10/2.8 lenses, or even Laowa 7mm, as the best options